# Accordion inside another accordion

Tags: accordion

Iam using ajax accordion. Is it possible to add an ajax accordion inside another accordion.

I tried adding this, but the accordion inside is not loading(not getting displayed)

```
<ajax:Accordion ID="accordionCountry" HeaderCssClass="headerStyle marginUpDown" HeaderSelectedCssClass="headerSelectedStyle" ContentCssClass="contentBackground" runat="server" SelectedIndex="-1" FadeTransitions="true" SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" TransitionDuration="250" FramesPerSecond="40" RequireOpenedPane="false" AutoSize="None">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlShowCategory" runat="server" CssClass="cursorPointer categoryPanelBackground marginUpDown">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="98%">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblCategoryName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryName") %>'
                                    CssClass="paddingLeft"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageAlign="Right" Height="20px" CssClass="verticalAlignMiddle" />
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCategoryId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("CategoryId") %>' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <ajax:Accordion ID="accordionCountry1" HeaderCssClass="headerStyle marginUpDown" HeaderSelectedCssClass="headerSelectedStyle"
                    ContentCssClass="contentBackground" runat="server" SelectedIndex="-1" FadeTransitions="true"
                    SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true" TransitionDuration="250" FramesPerSecond="40"
                    RequireOpenedPane="false" AutoSize="None">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server" CssClass="cursorPointer categoryPanelBackground marginUpDown">
                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="98%">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSubCategoryName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SubCategoryName") %>'
                                    CssClass="paddingLeft"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td align="right">
                                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" ImageAlign="Right" Height="20px" CssClass="verticalAlignMiddle" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </asp:Panel>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </ajax:Accordion>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajax:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use jQuery for accordion, it's better, check below link out :
click run after you click the link below

```
(function($) {

var allPanels = $('.accordion .dd').hide();

$('.accordion .dt  a').click(function() {
allPanels.slideUp();
$(this).parent().next().slideDown();
return false;
});
})(jQuery);
```

[Check This](http://jsfiddle.net/X9sz8/)